# Find Duplicate value From Collection Using Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

Using Lodash I am trying to find if a value exists in the collection or not.

If exists I want to return `true` else `false`.

```
 const d = [{
     "country": "India",
     "_id": ObjectId("5ad47b639048dd2367e95d48"),
     "cities": []
 }, {
     "country": "Spain",
     "_id": ObjectId("5ad47b639048dd2367e95d49"),
     "cities": []
 }];
```

**Snippet Code**

```
Countries = ['India', 'Spain']
if (_.has(d, Countries)) {
    console.log(true);
} else {
    console.log(false);
}
```

But it Always returns False. It's not recommended for me to use `lodash` can anyone suggests a better way if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ES6

You could use [`array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for checking duplicate  entries in array.

**DEMO**

```js
const d = [{
  "country": "India",
  "_id": "5ad47b639048dd2367e95d48",
  "cities": []
}, {
  "country": "Spain",
  "_id": "5ad47b639048dd2367e95d49",
  "cities": []
}];

const Countries = ['India', 'Spain'];

console.log(d.some(({country}) => Countries.includes(country)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the combination of `some` and `includes` methods. It will return `true`, if any item in `items` contains country from `countries` array.

```js
const items =  [
    {
        "country": "India",
        "_id": 'ObjectId("5ad47b639048dd2367e95d48")',
        "cities": []
    },
    {
        "country": "Spain",
        "_id": 'ObjectId("5ad47b639048dd2367e95d49")',
        "cities": []
    }
];

const countries = ['India', 'Spain'];
const includes = _.some(items, item => _.includes(countries , item.country));
console.log(includes);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without Lodash using Javascripts built in `filter` function

```
d.filter(item => item.country === "Spain"); //Would return an array of objects where the country's name property is Spain!
```

if we wanted to make this a boolean we could declare it as a variable and assert its length is greater than 0 like so:

```
let isSpanishCountry = d.filter(item => item.country === "Spain").length > 0; // console.log(isSpanishCountry) => true
```

Comment: but while comparison there is an array, not a single value

Comment: Very true! I missed that lodash `_.some` and `_.includes` is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Christian Bartram

```
var cities = [
　　{city: "Beijing",bOn:false},
　　{city: "Shanghai",bOn:false},
　　{city: "Chongqing",bOn:false},
　　{city: "Guangzhou",bOn:false}, {city: "Guangzhou",bOn:true},
　　{city: "Xi'an",bOn:false}
];

//Find duplicate element values in the array
_(cities).groupBy(x => x.city).pickBy(x => x.length > 1).keys().value()
```

*Return*

['Guangzhou']

```
//Find duplicate objects in an array
_.filter(_(cities).groupBy(x => x.city).value(),x => x.length > 1)
```

*Return*

[[{"city":"Guangzhou","bOn":false},{"city":"Guangzhou","bOn":true}]]